# how to import call from another directory? (python)

Tags: python, module, directory

I am trying to import a class named `DataHandler` into my `test_data_handler` file. I am doing this by stating `from handles.data_handler import DataHandler`. However, when I do this I get a error saying

> No module named 'handles'

If anyone knows how to get round this issue it would be greatly appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need add `__init__.py` file inside folder handles.
The `__init__.py` file lets the Python interpreter know that a directory contains code for a Python module.

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(1, '/path/to/application/app/folder')
from handles.data_handler import DataHandler
```

[Importing files from different folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder)

Comment: tried that but doesn't work

Comment: sorry, i edited the answer